# UIActivityIndicatorView when loading image from online?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios4, uiimageview, uiimage

I have a simple script that displays in a UIImageView from the internet.

Is there a way to display a UIActivityIndicatorView or something of that sort to show the user that it's loading?

Here's my minimal code:

```
NSString *imagePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"urlofimagehere.jpg"];
NSData *mydata = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imagePath]];
UIImage *myimage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:mydata];
[imageView setImage:myimage];
[myimage release];
```

Thanks!
Coulton

**EDIT:** CODE REMOVED

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
-[NSData initWithContentsOfURL:]
```

is a synchronous method. This means it will block until the data is loaded over the network. If you want to be able to keep your UI responsive, you'll want to use an asynchronous approach. For more info, read this: http://akosma.com/2010/05/28/initwithcontentsofurl-methods-considered-harmful/

I'd recommend using NSURLRequest with an NSURLRequestDelegate to receive callbacks when the data is finished loading. Here's an example:

```
- (void)loadImageAtURL(NSString *)urlString {
    [myUIActivityIndicatorView startAnimating];

    // SHOW NETWORK INDICATOR
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;

    // SET UP THE REQUEST
    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:urlString];
    NSURLRequest *request = [[[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url] autorelease];

    // SET UP THE CONNECTION
    connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    mutData = [[[NSMutableData alloc] init] retain];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection
  didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    // Handle error
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection
    didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    [mutData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)aConnection {

    // ONCE LOADED HIDE NETWORK INDICATOR
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;

    // RELEASE THE CONNECTION
    [connection release];

    // CREATE NEW UIIMAGE FROM THE DATA
    image = [[[UIImage alloc] initWithData:mutData] retain];
    [mutData release];

    // HIDE THE ACTIVITY INDICATOR
    // Make sure hidesWhenStopped is set to YES on the activity indicator.
    [myUIActivityIndicatorView stopAnimating];
    [myUIImageView setImage:image];
    [image release];
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I tried this, and it failed. Please see my updated post! Thanks.

Comment: There's probally many errors, I really didn't look over it before I posted it. Thanks again! PS: It failed on this line: `NSURLRequest *request = [[[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:imagePath] autorelease];`.

Comment: My apologies. initWithURL takes in an NSURL, not an NSString. You'll need to use -[NSURL initWithString:] See modified answer above.